# How can I put selected value of jquery multiselect dropdown into a hidden element's id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

How can I put selected value of jquery multiselect dropdown into a hidden element's id? I need that id be an array so I can get the selected values of the multiselect into that.

What I tried is:

```
$( "#Myselect" ).change(function(){
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        str += $( this ).val() + " ";
    });
    document.getElementById("objecttype").value = str; 
}).trigger( "change" );

<html:hidden styleId="objecttype" property="objecttype" name="Myobjecttype"/>
```

but objecttype is just an id and isn't an array!

Comment: please supply any code you have. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a sample what you've done so far.

Comment: @haxxxton I put my code in the question

Comment: @leon I put my code in the question

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by `but objecttype is just an id and isn't an array!`

Comment: @Cerlin Boss I mean when I iterate in the selected values of dropdown, I need to put them inside an array to post that in my code.

Comment: you are assigning the value of the selected items to the `.value` of `#objecttype`. are you trying to retrieve them again later? if so, you're joining your values with a `" "` so you'll need to `split` them based on that character to turn them back into an array

Comment: as `haxxxton` said if you have 1,2 and 3 as selected then you will get  `1 2 3` as a string. so if you want to convert it to an array then you have to use split (ie. `'1 2 3'.split(' ')`). in case if you want to post the data to server then you can post it as a string and split it in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want this hidden field to be posted somewhere and used later on (server-side or whatever). Take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hm71689h/ it is roughly what you wanted.

Take into account what Haxxxton just said: you're joining the values using a delimiter (in this example a comma by default). You need to split that value into a new array later on.

Also, in your code-sample, you're referring to the hidden field using: `document.getElementById("objecttype")`
But you did not use an identifier, you used a name. Although you might think it should be the same, an ID is not the same as the name of an element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need smth like this:

HTML:

```
<select name="choice" multiple id="mySelect">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="myObjecttype" />
```

JS:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
      //brand new array each time
    var foo = [];
      //fills the array
    foo = $("option:selected", this).map(function(){ return $(this).val() }).get();
      //fills input with vals, as strings of course
    $("input[name='myObjecttype']").val(foo);
      //logs an array, if needed
    console.log($("input[name='myObjecttype']").val().split(','));
});
```

Don't forget hidden input can't store array-/object- data, only strings. But you can easily make array.

See working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sfvx5Loj/1/